# Typescript derived class static property returns undefined. is it a bug or expected behaviour?

Tags: inheritance, typescript, static

I am learning typescript. I found one weird behavior. There are multiple instance of static property. in this case it is two one for `person` class and one for `student`  class. i checked with other language, in c# it is one instance, shared with declaring class and all the class derived form that class.

```
class person
{
    name : string 
    static maxAge : number
    constructor(name:string)
    {
        this.name = name
    }
}
class student extends person
{
    standard : string
    constructor(name:string,standard : string)
    {
        super(name);
        this.standard = standard;
    }
}
person.maxAge = 120;
console.log(person.maxAge);
console.log(student.maxAge);
```

My Questions are.

1. I want to understand that why static property not shared with the derived class?
2. Is compiler missing something here, and not able to give any compilation error?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to understand that why static property not shared with the derived class?

Its shared *at the moment of inheritance*. Instead of `person.maxAge = 120;` you should:

```
class person
{
    name : string 
    static maxAge : number = 120
    constructor(name:string)
    {
        this.name = name
    }
}
class student extends person
{
    standard : string
    constructor(name:string,standard : string)
    {
        super(name);
        this.standard = standard;
    }
}
console.log(person.maxAge);
console.log(student.maxAge);
```

> Is compiler missing something here, and not able to give any compilation error?

No. The compiler trusts you just like it would trust you if you said:

```
let foo: number;
console.log(foo); // No error
foo = 123;
```

The compiler isn't psychic (although TypeScript feels like that sometimes ) but tries its best to prevent *errors*.

Comment: setting value at time of declartion solves problem. but static property can be assigned later.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is shared, but since JavaScript is **prototype-based**, the property is shared through the **prototype chain**. When evaluating `student.maxAge`, the runtime will try to find from current object, and then its prototype, and then its prototype of prototype (the chain is created through inheritance), until `maxAge` is found in `person`'s prototype.

### [image]

2. There isn't any TypeScript nor JavaScript error in your code snippet.

Comment: This should get you start with prototypal inheritance https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain